# Social Tables data model

Tags: social-tables

I've just started looking at the documentation as we are going to need to integrate Salesforce with Social Tables shortly, so I am really new to Social Tables.

Specifically, we will need to sync data between the CRM and Social Tables Events and Guests, and maybe other objects, so it would be very helpful to have a data model or similar to check the relationships and fields available in Social Tables architecture.

I haven't found anything in the documentation, is there any way to get this, even if it's at a high level?

Thanks

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an integration with SocialTables you'll have to do a few manual steps, there is no way to do this completely programmatic from my experience. You'll also have to be prepared to contact SocialTables to get get correct guestlist ids. Also keep in mind that the API documentation isn't always correct, the API logic is also quite difficult to understand from time to time.

The first thing you need to do is figure out which version of the Venue Mapper you use. You'd want to use the 4.0 api and as far as I know this version of the api is only supported by Venue Mapper 3.0. I believe the Venue Mapper 3.0 is the frontend tool SocialTables provides to do the venue planning.

In social tables an event has two ids, one numerical one and one alpha-numerical one, when you use the 4.0/events endpoint you only get the alpha-numerical event id, and your going to need the numerical one. The only way I've been able to get the numerical id is to pull it out from the url when using the Venue Mapper, example of the url follows below:

```
https://plan.socialtables.com/team/{team_id}/event/{event_id}/space/{space_id}
```

Now you need to get the guestlist id, you can get that by using the following url, using the numerical event id:

```
GET https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/diagrams?event={numerical_event_id}
```

This endpoint return a json structure where one of the parameters is "guestlist_id".

Please be aware that the guestlist id you get from this endpoint might not be the correct one. I struggled quite a bit with this part and ended up with SocialTables sending me the guestlist id by email.

To get the guests in your guestlist use the following api endpoint:

```
GET https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id}
```

The *{guestlist_id}* is an alpha-numerical string similar to: *cfdac1c0-yb1d-12e6-84a5-a39e92131645*

And by that you should hopefully get access to your guests.

Comment: Kristian, that is much more than a great answer, thanks! At this moment I am working on some other stuff so I will not be able to test this step by step to confirm on my side, but it makes perfect sense and it turns out to be an excellent explanation to my question. I will update my answer as soon as I've been able to work on this. I really appreciate your help and your time ;-)

Comment: @DannyMarfil Happy I could help, keep me posted on your progress :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for using our API.

To answer your question, the best way to see the data model at the moment is to access our developer portal and use the API console to see what is returned.  For events you will need to know the team id of the team you are working with use the team events endpoint to get access to the event ids.

https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Events/get_4_0_legacyvm3_teams_team_events

This will return some basic information about each event for that team.  You can then request additional details for specific events by using this endpoint:

https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Events/get_4_0_legacyvm3_events_event

Comment: Thanks ddombrow, that is what I was guessing but didn't lose anything by asking.

Comment: I am struggling with Guests though, as I need to get the list of guests for a particular event. From the API console I believe I need to provide the Guest List for any guest endpoint, but in order to get the guest list, I see I need to provide the Session id, which I don't know where to get it from.
This is why I thought a data model would be useful, can you help with this?

Comment: @DannyMarfil I do believe that the GET /4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id} should return the session id. At least that is what the documentation says, still I have not tested this myself.

Comment: Thanks Kristian, the thing is I don't know the guestlist_id. According to the documentation, if I want to get the guestlists, I need to call: /4.0/sessions/{session_id}/guestlists
But then I need the session_id, but when I call /4.0/events/{event_id}/sessions, I am not getting any sessions at all?
I am afraid I am stuck here...

Comment: So in definitive, I need to get a list of guests for a given event - knowing the event_id - but I don't seem to be able to find the way.
Have you managed to do this?

Comment: Do you know if your event is on the Venue Mapper 3.0 version? I do believe that the 4.0 api only support the 3.0 version of the venue mapper. And that is probably why the 4.0/sessions.... endpoint don't give you the correct data. I'd suggest contacting Social Tables and get your event upgraded to Venue Mapper 3.0.

Comment: I have no clue - will check with them. In any case, is this something you have had to do before? I mean retrieving the list of guest of an event. If so, could you please explain the API calls you have to do to get this? In such case, create an answer - not a comment - and I will mark it as best answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyMarfil, let me try to setup a proper answer for you