# salesforce social tables integration

Tags: social-tables

I have been looking at Social Tables and Salesforce Integration. I did a thorough analysis of out-of-the-box (OOTB) integration capability of Social Tables for Salesforce, however the integration process does not seem to suit our needs.

I came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042318/social-tables-data-model) where I got some information about API integration. There, I saw that API endpoint required to get guests included the guestlist_id. The question is, how would the API endpoint look like if I plan to fetch the guestlist on the basis of a custom field on an event in Social Tables. If I pass the Campaign Id when importing guests from Salesforce to Social Tables as a custom field, can I use that field for fetching guests through API?

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't have support for querying against custom/metadata fields. This is something I will pass to our product team. But unfortunately we don't currently support it.